# Bootstrap show div on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, mousehover

Is there any way to show `Div` on mouse hover on any html elements like `td`

Div has the HTML content in it.

[image]

Comment: Asking a question on SO shouldn't be the first thing you do when you're stuck. You should try to research and answer your question on your own first. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with CSS.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="to-hover">
    <div id="to-show"></div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
#to-show {
    display: none;
}
#to-hover:hover > #to-show {
    display: block; 
}
```

You may need to change block to inline or some other value depending on the situation. Also you might need to use a different selector than `>` if they divs have a different relationship.

Answer (score 2):

There is "Bootstrap Popover Plugin" : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp

like that:

```
  <div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content">Hover over me</a>
  </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

Another example on table element:  (hover "Savings")

https://jsfiddle.net/yrgLenjg/

Comment: You show me simple popover of tooltip but I need Popover that will be the HTML and it will contain so many different types of elements.

Comment: @user2972061 You can use this code inside any HTML element just write inside the element: data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content" (P.s: look at the edit)